# Intl.DateTimeFormat options hash: Getting leading zeros with '2-digit'

Tags: javascript, date-formatting

```
Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', {
    weekday: 'long',
    year: 'numeric',
    month: 'long',
    day: '2-digit',
    hour: '2-digit',
    minute: '2-digit',
    second: '2-digit'
}).format(807959700000)
```

I expected the above call to return something like `Wednesday, August 09, 1995, 04:15:00 AM` but it seems the leading zero for the hour is missing. I get `Wednesday, August 09, 1995, 4:15:00 AM`

`2-digit` does not do the trick, though it seems to work for the day of the month. Does `2-digit` mean something else than I expect, or am I doing something wrong?

P.S. I tested this in the Chrome console, nowhere else.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This will work if you set `hour12` property to **false**. i.e.

```
Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', {
    weekday: 'long',
    year: 'numeric',
    month: 'long',
    day: '2-digit',
    hour: '2-digit',
    minute: '2-digit',
    second: '2-digit',
    hour12: false     // setting 24 hour format 
}).format(807959700000);
```

It works for both 2am and also 2pm(14hr). But I know the same should work for 12 hour format too, but it is not. I checked in both chrome and firefox browsers.

When I checked the specs, it has defined an [algorithm](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-402/1.0/#FormatDateTime) which can be used to implement `Intl.DateTimeFormat` functionality. I saw there were many special cases handled when hour12 property to set true, and one of the last step is

> 8. If dateTimeFormat has an internal property [[hour12]] whose value is
>      **true**, then
>
>    - If pm is true, then let fv be an implementation and locale
>        dependent String value representing “post meridiem”; else let fv be an
>        implementation and locale dependent String value representing “ante
>        meridiem”.
>    - Replace the substring of result that consists of "{ampm}",
>        with fv.

So I think, the `Intl.DateTimeFormat` initially works with date object, later at step(8), it applies this step to put am/pm information.

During this step, may be `2-digits` information specified in `Intl.DateTimeFormat` **is not considered, but it has to be**. I think this is a valid [bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=527926) and it is already raised https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=527926.

---

PS: I'm not saying issue is in specs, as described in the ECMAScript Language Specification,

> Algorithms are
>   used to precisely specify the required semantics of ECMAScript
>   constructs, but are not intended to imply the use of any specific
>   implementation technique.

Comment: What a bummer. So if the leading zeros were REALLY important to me (and they are not) is there a better namespace for this than Intl.DateTimeFormat?

Comment: I've always used our own custom library for Date related stuff. So I suggest to use that, because in future if we want to switch from one api set to another, there will be change only in our custom library not in any other place. If you like to use other frameworks, you can use moment.js but I've not worked on it.

Answer (score 16):

This still does NOT work on **Chrome Version 79** or **Node.js v13.7.0**!

They both ignore the `2-digit` format. Here's a quick test case:

```
d = new Date('2020-01-01T03:04:09Z') 
new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', { minute: '2-digit'}).format(d) //"4"

//should return "04" but it actually returns "4"
```

Please comment on this post when you see it's fixed.

---

Update 06-22-2021:

Still doesn't work on
`Chrome Version 91.0.4472.106`
`Node.Js v14.15.4`

---

Update 12-09-2022:

Tested on `Chrome Version 108.0.5359.98`. Still doesn't work.

---

Update 07-31-2023:

Tested on `Chrome Version 115.0.5790.110`. Still doesn't work.

Comment: As a solution, you can use the -> "hourCycle/ hc" property. But it is not included in every Intl.DataTimeFormatOptions library. Either I could find to use it. But this is the easy fix for this problem.

Comment: Although you're right, I thinks it's important to note that when you add the hour field, it actually does return '04' for the minute:

`const d = new Date('2020-01-01T03:04:09Z'); new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', { hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit'}).format(d); // returns: "04:04 AM"`